# How to create nested subcommands with structopt?

Tags: rust, structopt

## Introduction

I currently have subcommands working using `structopt`, similarly to this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61351721/10860175). However I would like to have nested subcommands similarly of how `docker` works:

```
docker image ls
docker image pull
```

## Current Code

main.rs

```rust
mod cli;

use structopt::StructOpt;
use crate::cli::{Opt, Command};

fn main() {

    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    match opt.cmd {
        Command::Subcommand { .. } => {
            // Do something
        }
    }

}
```

cli/mod.rs

```rust
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub enum Command {
    Subcommand {
       // args
    }
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Opt {
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    pub cmd: Command,
}
```

### What I have tried

Added another struct:
main.rs

```rust
mod cli;

use structopt::StructOpt;
use crate::cli::{Opt, Resource};

fn main() {

    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    match opt.resource {
        Resource::Command { .. } => {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

cli/mod.rs

```rust
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub enum Command {
    Subcommand {
        // args
    }
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Resource {
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    image: Image
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Opt {
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    pub resource: Resource,
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<Resource as Trait>::ImageCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since command is described as an enum, a subcommand would be a "sub-enum" (an enum inside an enum variant). In the example below ImageCommand is an enum inside a Command enum variant:

```rust
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct ImagePullOptions {
    pub name: String,
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub enum ImageCommand {
    #[structopt(name = "ls")]
    List,
    Pull(ImagePullOptions),
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub enum Command {
    Image(ImageCommand),
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Options {
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    pub command: Command,
}

fn main() {
    let options: Options = Options::from_args();
    match options.command {
        Command::Image(image_command) => {
            match image_command {
                ImageCommand::List => println!("listing..."),
                ImageCommand::Pull(pull_options) => println!("pulling {}...", pull_options.name),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test with:

```
$ cargo run -- image 

USAGE:
    testsubopt image <SUBCOMMAND>

FLAGS:
    -h, --help       Prints help information
    -V, --version    Prints version information

SUBCOMMANDS:
    help    Prints this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)
    ls      
    pull
```

```
$ cargo run -- image pull asd
pulling asd...
```